# How to avoid calling the database again when I already have all I need in the result of the SQL call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, caching, coding-style

In my application I have a complex database structure. In order to generate the JSON response for a call, I need to get data from many joined tables.

I created a SQL query that fetched all the data I need (using rails' `includes`). however, now that I have the result in my view, I can't figure what is the right way to actually render it.

***A simplified example, not my actual code:*** Let's say I have **Project** that contains **SubProjects** that contain **Tasks** and that the query returns some nested structure of them all, filtered according to some logic.

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  def with_sub_projects_visible_by(user)
    includes(...complex join with sub projects and tasks...)
    .where(...complex condition...)
  end
end
```

In the controller I have something like this:

```
  def show
    @project_with_full_details = Project.find(params[:id]).with_sub_projects_visible_by(current_user)
  end
```

Is there a way to write simple view code that will render a page that contains all the data from `@project_with_full_details` without calling the database again? From what I tried, simply calling `@project_with_full_details.sub_projects` doesn't do the trick. It calls the database and gets me the full list of related sub_projects instead of the filtered one that should be contained in the query results.

(I'm using RABL for my view, since I'm rendering JSON, but it's less important, ERB example will be totally fine)

Comment: just doing `includes(:tasks)` should do eager loading for you and make only one join query to get the object and the relevant tasks associations.
`includes(...complex join with sub projects and tasks...)` doesn't make the most sence , if you wanna do a very complex join with custom queries you need `join()` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActiveRecord provides a preloader for associations which causes Rails to only load the objects from the database once (it also happens before the page is loaded).

For your example, it would probably look something like this:

```
@project = Project.find(params[:id])
ActiveRecord::Associations::Preloader.new(
  @project, [ :subprojects, subprojects: :tasks]
)
```

That would at least give you the desired effect of only running the SQL once.

If your models look something like this:

```
class Project
  has_many :users
  has_many :sub_projects
  has_many :tasks, through: :sub_projects
  ...
end
```

Then perhaps you could define a method like `subprojects_for(user)`. Then you should be able to do something along these lines:

```
# controller
@project = Project.find(params[:id])
@subprojects = @project.subprojects_for(current_user)

# haml
.project
  = @project.title
  - @project.subprojects_for(current_user).each do |subproject|
    = Something for subprojects...
    - subproject.tasks.each do |task|
      = You get the idea
```

The real magic should have happened in the preloader, though. I assume you've looked at the server logs to see that the SQL is being run more than once?

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. I did look at the server logs and see that the SQL is being run more than once. I tried something similar to this approach, but my problem is that the subprojects_for (like) method is quite complex in my case and goes to the database. Will using the preloader as you showed cause this to run in memory?

Comment: It's hard to say without knowing what your `with_sub_projects_visible_by` needs to do. Presumably you have `User`, `Subproject`, and `SubprojectPermission` models, or something along those lines? Could you just do something like `SubprojectPermission.where(user: 4).map(&:subproject)`?

Comment: No. calculating the permissions on the subproejcts involves some complex logic: checking who is the user who owns it and what is her relation with the current user. It involves some more database tables. This is why I initially thought it would be a good idea to have that logic as part of the model and only return the result of the computation to the view...

Comment: I don't want to dictate how to write your app, but is it possible to generate some sort of Permission model? You could create/destroy Permissions as your User's relationships change using update hooks. It would save you a lot more time in rendering this view than it would to only run the complicated SQL once.

Comment: And I'm not sure whether the Preloader will help you with this. I didn't realize how complicated your setup was. You could try it and see... Associations::Preloader is easy to set up.

Comment: I guess you have a good point there. I'll rethink my model. Thanks for helping.